# Color changes when turning Blob from SQLite database to a bitmap and then a mat

Tags: java, android, opencv, bitmap

So I have this image which i put in a Blob in my SQLite database 
[image]

What I do next is read out the blob from the Database (so I turn the blob into a bitmap).
Then I turn this bitmap into a Mat (cause I need to use it for my feature descriptor) BUT  I end up with is the following Mat:

[image]

As you can see, the colors are all wrong. This is my code:

```
    BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        bmpFactoryOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                        bmpFactoryOptions.inScaled = false;
                        bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight = 240;
                        bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth = 320;
                        // decodes the blob back into a bitmap
                        byte[] blob = contact.getMP();
                        ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(blob);
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                        Bitmap scalen = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 320, 240, false);
Mat ImageMat = new Mat();
                        Utils.bitmapToMat(scalen, ImageMat);
```

I need the output image to be just the same as the input, what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

When I read the bitmap image with

```
    try {
                        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("mnt/sdcard/test.png");
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                 }
```

it gives back the image With the right colors,so the Color changing has to do with converting the bitmap to a Mat.

Comment: It appears as if the red and blue values got exchanged. How are you displaying the `Mat`?

Comment: `String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
          filename += "/MATCheck_";
          SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd_HH-mm-ss");
          Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
          String dateString = fmt.format(date);
          filename += dateString;
          filename += ".png";      
          Highgui.imwrite(filename, ImageMat);`

The code works great for the other images which i save in the exact same way. (doesn't use the database, but Mat img2 = Highgui.imread("mnt/sdcard/blablabla.png");